# Getting an error when trying to use scanner to take a user's input and then repeat it

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DifferentTypesOfInput {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("type");
        String userInput = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(userInput);
```

I am having an error where on the `String userInput = scanner.nextLine();` line, I am getting an error message "cannot find symbol, symbol: variable scanner, location: class DifferentTypesOfInput". I am using Java 8 and I have used the scanner function fine until now. I am not sure what I did wrong so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you used the wrong variable name for `scanner.nextLine()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is simple you are using -

```
String userInput = scanner.nextLine();
```

But you defined

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)
```

So you should use scan instead of scanner

```
String userInput = scan.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined scanner object as "scan" and trying to access it as "scanner", make sure you will use the defined object it will resolve this error.